# Excel Restore defaults sheet formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to setup a dynamic Excel restore defaults sheet formula that takes 2 variables: field name address and field value address. Actually that part is already done, but let me share an example of what i want to achieve:
I have a sheet with:

- A1 [Field title],
- B1 [Field value that i need to restore to default when C1 link is clicked]
- C1 [Hiperlink cell with VBA formula that only updates on click because of the #] formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#restoreDefaultForRange(" & CELL("address",A1) & ",B1)","⭯")
```

I will share the VBA code at the end of the post.
The formula works, instead of B1 I can even use B1:B3 to restore all cells in that region, and i can use 3 regions divided by "," eg: B1,B2:B4,B5, and it will restore all cells in the specified region.

The issue is that while the A1 part is dynamic(and if I add/remove rows/columns, the reference will move with them) B2 is just text, so it will not update.

**Is there a similar formula similar to CELL("address",A1), that works for a Region, and not for a single cell so i can make the second part of the formula dynamic as well?**

To answer @Variatus I will add a few more details:
It would be nice if it would be this simple, but I have allot of variance to cover:

- Both variables (Field value and Field target) can be in different position relative to the link formula, A1 B1 C1 is the simplest example I could give but it's usually A2, B2:B5, B1 (so clicking on the hyperlink in B1 will restore all cells in B2:B5 to their default value, and in A2 is the field name)
- The cells to restore can be 1 cell, or multiple cells that might not be 1 near the other, like B2, B5, C10
- I need to create a sheet formula, so my manager who does not know VBA can also update them, to take a bit of my workload, because I've been swamped lately and I hate letting my 3y old watch so much tv.

```
VBA:
Function restoreDefaultForRange(targetName, targetRange As Range, Optional targetRange1 As Range, Optional targetRange2 As Range)
  Set restoreDefaultForRange = Selection
  restoreDefaultInputsForRange targetName, targetRange, targetRange1, targetRange2
End function
Private Sub restoreDefaultInputsForRange(targetName, targetRange As Range, Optional targetRange1 As Range, Optional targetRange2 As Range)
    Dim cellTitle, cellI As Range, rngI, cellCounter As Long
    Dim I As Long, MSG As String

    If budgetStatus = StatusInProgress Or budgetStatus = StatusReview Then
        cellTitle = targetName
        cellCounter = 0

        'GET MESSAGE BY LOOPING THROUGH OPTIONAL RANGES
        For Each rngI In Array(targetRange, targetRange1, targetRange2) ' FOR EACH OF THE RANGES, INCLUDING OPTIONAL
            If Not rngI Is Nothing Then                                 '  IF OPTIONAL IS DEFINED
                cellCounter = cellCounter + rngI.Cells.Count
                MSG = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(", ", True, MSG, targetRange.Address(0, 0))
            End If
        Next
        MSG = "[ " & cellCounter & IIf(cellCounter > 1, " cells - ", " cell - ") & MSG & " ]"

        If vbYes = MsgBox("Restore the default formulas for: " & vbNewLine _
                    & "'" & cellTitle & "'" & vbNewLine _
                    & MSG & vbNewLine _
                    & "", _
                     vbYesNo, "Restore defaults ?") Then


            'UNIVERSAL RESTORE DEFAULT FOR TARGET CELL
            For Each rngI In Array(targetRange, targetRange1, targetRange2) ' FOR EACH OF THE RANGES, INCLUDING OPTIONAL
                If Not rngI Is Nothing Then                                 '  IF OPTIONAL IS DEFINED
                    For Each cellI In rngI.Cells                            '   FOR EACH CELL IN RANGE
                       restoreDefaultsForCell cellI                         '    RESTORE REFAULTS
                    Next
                End If
            Next

            setProgramAlertsOn
            restoreDefaultsMode = False

            MsgBox "Finished restoring defaults", vbOKOnly, "Done"
        End If
     Else
         messageRestoreDefaults
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why so complicated? It seems all you want is to call your function `RestoreDefaultForRange` with a few parameters. It seems you want this done with a single click. No problem - until you use a hyperlink for the job. Wouldn't you prefer to enter the cell ranges you want to update in A1, the values to update in B1, and just click or double-click on C1 to execute the update?

Comment: @Variatus You asked a valid question, which i answered in the initial question.

Comment: I have two more questions. (1) If you want to restore the default values for B2:B5 wouldn't you need a range of similar size to hold 3 default values? Does A2 hold and array of 3 values? Or is the one value in A2 the default for all 3 cells?

Comment: (2) Is the range triangle B1, B2:B5, A2 an absolutely fixed location, a relatively fixed location or a variable location? Absolute means none of the 3 cells ever moves (although there may be other triangles elsewhere), relative means the triangle can move but the 3 cells stay in the same location relative to each other, like adding rows or columns. Variable would be when you might add a triangle of any shape at the spur of a moment, wherever you happen to need it, and perhaps delete it tomorrow or replace it with one of different shape, like moving A2 to C7.